# CentOS 6.4 64-bit Memory Usage really not adding up

Tags: linux, memory, top

I recently migrated hosting providers and in the process my distribution changed from CentOS 5.9 64-bit to CentOS 6.4 64-bit. Despite having a little more RAM (1 GiB rather than 768 MiB) the new VPS running CentOS 6.4 is always out of memory however. At first I suspected buffers and cache but the values returned by free don't seem to agree. Here are some outputs.

top

```
top - 14:16:22 up 13:27,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks:  44 total,   1 running,  43 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1048576k total,  1048576k used,        0k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,        0k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
17678 tomcat    18   0 1772m 182m  42m S  0.0 17.8   0:09.80 java
 3663 root      15   0 89788  21m 1960 S  0.0  2.1   0:00.70 miniserv.pl
 3355 mysql     18   0  498m  20m 5872 S  0.0  2.0   0:01.31 mysqld
16358 root      18   0  403m  14m 8364 S  0.0  1.4   0:00.09 httpd
16360 apache    15   0  403m 7344  768 S  0.0  0.7   0:00.00 httpd
 3692 root      18   0 71780 3708 2864 S  0.0  0.4   0:02.37 sshd
 3751 root      16   0 71780 3624 2828 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.03 sshd
 3422 root      15   0 82504 2364  736 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.13 sendmail
 3170 haldaemo  15   0 24752 2316 1948 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 hald
 3430 smmsp     18   0 78232 2092  692 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 sendmail
 3694 root      15   0 11580 1888 1416 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.16 bash
 3143 root      18   0  243m 1576 1092 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.03 rsyslogd
    1 root      15   0 19232 1528 1288 S  0.0  0.1   0:19.65 init
 3253 root      19   0 11308 1492 1236 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 mysqld_safe
13451 sockd     15   0 91792 1308  752 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sockd
 3387 sockd     18   0 91792 1304  752 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.37 sockd
 3527 root      15   0 21308 1272  684 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.02 crond
```

vmstat -s ; free

```
      1048576  total memory
      1048576  used memory
            0  active memory
            0  inactive memory
            0  free memory
            0  buffer memory
            0  swap cache
            0  total swap
            0  used swap
            0  free swap
        37863 non-nice user cpu ticks
            0 nice user cpu ticks
        14367 system cpu ticks
    116512866 idle cpu ticks
           30 IO-wait cpu ticks
            0 IRQ cpu ticks
            0 softirq cpu ticks
            0 stolen cpu ticks
       413960 pages paged in
     15754892 pages paged out
            0 pages swapped in
            0 pages swapped out
            0 interrupts
   1704963753 CPU context switches
   1395474517 boot time
     46700605 forks
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1048576    1048576          0          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:    1048576          0
Swap:            0          0          0
```

smem

```
  PID User     Command                         Swap      USS      PSS      RSS
 3390 sockd    sockd:                             0      136      145      820
13451 sockd    sockd:                             0      128      172     1308
13450 sockd    sockd:                             0      136      173      916
13452 sockd    sockd:                             0      136      173      916
13448 sockd    sockd:                             0      152      181      916
13459 sockd    sockd:                             0      160      185      916
13454 sockd    sockd:                             0      176      190      916
13455 sockd    sockd:                             0      176      190      916
13456 sockd    sockd:                             0      176      190      916
13457 sockd    sockd:                             0      176      190      916
13458 sockd    sockd:                             0      176      190      916
13449 sockd    sockd:                             0      136      192     1080
 7205 sockd    sockd:                             0      180      197      916
 7208 sockd    sockd:                             0      180      197      916
 7240 sockd    sockd:                             0      180      197      916
 7243 sockd    sockd:                             0      180      197      916
13453 sockd    sockd:                             0      184      197      916
 3637 root     /usr/sbin/atd                      0      200      200      480
 7234 sockd    sockd:                             0      188      201      916
 7237 sockd    sockd:                             0      188      201      916
 3217 root     xinetd -stayalive -pidfile         0      228      232      984
 3171 root     hald-runner                        0      196      240     1268
    1 root     ini                                0      240      254     1528
 3253 root     /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_saf        0      256      270     1492
 3387 sockd    sockd -D                           0      268      303     1304
 3378 root     /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /var        0       40      326      964
 3379 root     /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /var        0       40      326      660
 1233 root     /sbin/udevd -d                     0      376      377      700
 3143 root     /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/        0      484      498     1576
 3694 root     -bash                              0      472      516     1888
 3527 root     crond                              0      588      589     1272
 3160 dbus     dbus-daemon --system               0      620      622     1012
 3209 root     /usr/sbin/sshd                     0      684      687     1212
 3170 haldaemon hald                               0      812      889     2316
 3751 root     sshd: root                         0      804      987     3624
 3692 root     sshd: root@pts/0                   0      876     1059     3708
 3430 smmsp    sendmail: Queue runner@01:0        0     1400     1411     2092
 3422 root     sendmail: accepting connect        0     1628     1644     2364
16360 apache   /usr/sbin/httpd                    0      168     3376     7344
16358 root     /usr/sbin/httpd                    0      344     3810    14912
17766 root     python /usr/sbin/smem              0     5684     5752     7580
 3355 mysql    /usr/libexec/mysqld --based        0    15248    16070    21120
 3663 root     /usr/bin/perl /usr/libexec/        0    19728    19909    21648
17678 tomcat   /usr/java/latest/bin/../bin        0   184952   185049   186656
```

cat /proc/meminfo

```
MemTotal:      1048576 kB
MemFree:             0 kB
Buffers:             0 kB
Cached:              0 kB
SwapCached:          0 kB
Active:              0 kB
Inactive:            0 kB
HighTotal:           0 kB
HighFree:            0 kB
LowTotal:      1048576 kB
LowFree:             0 kB
SwapTotal:           0 kB
SwapFree:            0 kB
Dirty:               0 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
AnonPages:           0 kB
Mapped:              0 kB
Slab:                0 kB
PageTables:          0 kB
NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
Bounce:              0 kB
CommitLimit:         0 kB
Committed_AS:        0 kB
VmallocTotal:        0 kB
VmallocUsed:         0 kB
VmallocChunk:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:     0
HugePages_Free:      0
HugePages_Rsvd:      0
Hugepagesize:     2048 kB
```

These numbers only add up to 250 MiB or so. I wonder if it owuld help to reprovision the VPS to CentOS 5.9 32-bit bit, but then I would have to change some 64-bit applications.

Comment: What sort of virtualization is this? (Try running `virt-what` to identify it.) Those are obviously not valid values.

Comment: virt-what comes back with openvz

Answer (score 1):

With OpenVZ, the memory values you get are basically meaningless. The only meaningful values you get are the resident set size of each process. OpenVZ manages physical memory and swap as a system resource across containers. It is generally considered a low-cost, low-performance option, particularly because it gives a very low level of memory and CPU isolation between containers.

Comment: If I'm to understand then, I'm not actually getting the 1 GiB I'm paying to have?

Comment: @AltonXL I can think of several different things you could mean by that, some of which are correct and some of which are not.